# No git history in Visual Studio 2017 (possibly after subtree merge)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

After merging two projects into one git repository, the history of (only) one of the directories of the target projects seemed to be lost - when right clicking the file in solution explorer and "View History..." there was nothing. But: new commits for the file also did not appear in the history. I am not 100% sure if the merge caused this issues, we merged the repos 5 weeks ago and noticed the problem a little later - it seemed obvious that the merge was related but I am no git expert.

Strangely, when using the solution explorer folder view (same right click - "View History..."), all is fine, full history (before an after merge) is available, codelens, everything.

Also, when selecting the file in an commit in repo history and "View History..." - history is there. Is this a VS issue or does someone have an explanation?

Comment: "Is this a VS issue?" Perhaps you could install GitExtensions (which is a lot better at displaying history) to cross check.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, I just did that and history looks fine there. Strange finding: in the filetree in GitExtensions the directory with the lost history exists twice, but with different capitalization. I can however not delete the superfluous directory (which is almost empty) since it only appears in the filetree, not in the Git bash.

Comment: That should be a part of the explanation. Git is case sensitive but windows folder, no. So when asking for the history of the folder, it takes the one which is mostly empty... Not easy to solve. I advice to rename the folder to a completely different name, commit and rename to the original name and commit again to end up with only one folder...

Comment: Great, that fixed it, thank you. I had to "mv MyDir MyDirTemp", and check in. The superfluous "mydir" directory was still visible in Git Extensions but not in git bash. I then renamed the dir again with "mv MyDir mydir" and that resulted in a perfectly fine project with history. If you care you could make this an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a VS issue?

**You could install GitExtensions (which is a lot better at displaying history) to cross check.**

> I just did that and history looks fine there. Strange finding: in the filetree in GitExtensions the directory with the lost history exists twice, but with different capitalization.

That should be a part of the explanation. Git is case sensitive but windows folder, no.

So when asking for the history of the folder, it takes the one which is mostly empty... Not easy to solve.

**I advice to rename the folder to a completely different name, commit and rename to the original name and commit again to end up with only one folder...**